# Need help with libcurl username/password authentication

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to access a secure webpage on one of our servers.  The webpage is inside a .htaccess protected directory that requires a username and password.  I'm trying to get libcurl to submit the authentication request so it can access the file.  After finding some guidance in various places, I've come up with what I believe should work, but it doesn't.

```
$url="https://www.myurl.com/htaccess_secured_directory/file.php";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'myusername:mypassword');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

The file.php file should simply echo "Hello World!", but the $result variable is coming up blank.  Is there a way to get error messages back from curl?  Am I doing something wrong?  I've also used CURLLAUTH_ALL without success, but I believe I just have basic authorization anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `curl_errno()` and `curl_error()` to retrieve error information, ie:

```
$url="https://www.myurl.com/htaccess_secured_directory/file.php";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'myusername:mypassword');
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch))
{
  echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{    
  echo $result;
}

curl_close($ch);
```

The available error codes are documented [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html).

Comment: Thanks!  That helped me find that curl didn't like the ssl cert on the remote server for some reason.  I added the following options to solve the problem: 

curl_setopt( $ch , CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , false );
curl_setopt( $ch , CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST , false );