# XML Request Using Simple Link

Tags: php, api, rest

I have following link that give XML data. I want to call that link through my php page. Also when i calling this link, i have to provide user name and password to get page xml. How all this can be possible through php.

https://interface.callport.net:8080/P-RVWR-drcm01-cti/call/2142100570?query_type=caller_info&dnis=8883874944

Comment: The user/password is via HTTP Basic Auth. Lookup how to use curl with Basic Auth.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350030/need-help-with-libcurl-username-password-authentication) has an example which should provide all the info you need.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, Thanks for your help. I have used that example but got the error message "Curl error: couldn't connect to host"

Comment: You should post a new question then which contains the code you tried, and all necessary information about the error message received.

Comment: $url="https://interface.callport.net:8080/P-RVWR-drcm01-cti/call/2142100570";
    $curl_post_data = array("query_type"=>'caller_info',"dnis"=>'8883874944');
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,base64_encode('**'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$curl_post_data);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_errno($ch)){
      echo curl_error($ch);
    }else{    
      echo $result;
    }
    curl_close($ch);

Comment: As I suggested, please post this as a new question, not in the comments here.